# Faiss : How to create an Index of 10M vectors of size 1024

Tags: python, memory, faiss

I want to create an index of nearly 10M vectors of size 1024. Here is the code that I used.

```
import numpy as np
import faiss  
import random                

f = 1024

vectors = []
no_of_vectors=10000000
for k in range(no_of_vectors):
    v = [random.gauss(0, 1) for z in range(f)]
    vectors.append(v)
        
np_vectors = np.array(vectors).astype('float32')

index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(f)  
index.add(np_vectors)                 

faiss.write_index(index, "faiss_index.index")
```

The code is worked for a small number of vectors. But the memory limit exceeds when the number of vectors is about 2M. I used `index.add()` instead of appending vectors to list(vectors=[]). But it didn't work as well.

I want to know how to create an index for large number of vectors.

Comment: Why do you need 10M vectors of size 1024?! This is incredibly HUGE!!?!

Comment: I am creating a document similarity checking tool. It consists of a large database of documents. I need to add laser embeddings of all sentences into the index. There are about 10M.

Comment: Hmm, maybe use numpy or pandas?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to continue using Faiss, there is a reference for choosing a different index, maybe HNSW or IVFPQ.

ref: https://wangzwhu.github.io/home/file/acmmm-t-part3-ann.pdf go the last page.

[image]

And another option is to try some distributed solutions, such as [Milvus](https://milvus.io), which build top of Ann library like faiss

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31271899)